# How to create OLAP cube using azure data lake store?

Tags: azure, ssas, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, olap-cube

I have 3 csv data sets. I want to create an OLAP cube so that it creates a schema joining all the 3 data sets. How can we do it in Azure? Can we use Azure data lake for this?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure, data held in OLTP systems such as Azure SQL Database is copied into the OLAP system, such as Azure Analysis Services.

[image]

In Azure, all of the following data stores will meet the core requirements for OLAP:

- SQL Server with Columnstore indexes
- Azure Analysis Services SQL
- Server Analysis Services (SSAS)

For more details, refer “[OLAP in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/architecture/data-guide/relational-data/online-analytical-processing#olap-in-azure)” and "[Defining and Deploying a Cube](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-tutorial/lesson-2-defining-and-deploying-a-cube?view=sql-server-2017)".

Hope this helps.